# Why is "erstmal" not recognized by my spellchecker and is "erstmals" correct?

Tags: word-choice

I typed the following sentence in an E-Mail in Thunderbird:

> Muss man sich erstmal einloggen?

The German spellchecker said "erstmal" is not a word and suggested that it be replaced with "erstmals".

But `Muss man sich erstmals einloggen?` doesn't sound right to me.

Which is correct in this sentence, `erstmal` or `erstmals`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case *erstmals* is not the right word, because it means "the first time" as in

> Die Fußball-Weltmeisterschaft fand erstmals 1930 in Uruguay statt.

If you want to use "erstmal", I would suggest writing it in the "two-words" form:

> Muss man sich **erst mal** einloggen?

which is a colloquial expression. A more formal version could be

> Muss man sich **zuerst (einmal)** einloggen?

Comment: Also bitte mal eine klare Aussage. Ist **erstmal** richtig oder falsch?

Comment: "Erst mal" ist ohne Zweifel richtig. "Erstmal" - nicht sicher. "Erstmals" ist falsch, außer wenn man sich zum allerersten mal einlogged. "Erstmals" einloggen kann man sich nur einmal.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erst_mal) *"erstmal"* or *"erst mal"* (both is allowed) are **colloquial** abbreviations of *"erst einmal"* in the meaning of *"zunächst"*.

> Muss man sich zunächst einloggen?

Both *"erstmals"*, and *"erstmalig"* are appropriate adverbs to denote something happening for the first time. This is likely to be a different meaning than in your example - unless it was some e.g. activation procedure that had to be done only once. If used, then "*erstmalig*" sounds better in the sense of a high standard, may be because it is also a bit old-fashioned.