# Können Rechtschreibprüfprogrammen helfen zu entscheiden, ob Worte getrennt oder zusammengeschrieben werden?

Tags: compound

Hier in German.stackexchange.com finde ich eine Frage bezüglich [erstmal vs erst mal](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/why-is-erstmal-not-recognized-by-my-spellchecker-and-is-erstmals-correct) und auf http://english.stackexchange.com habe ich gerade eine Frage bezüglich [intranet vs intra-net](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44623/is-intranet-a-correct-english-word) gestellt.

Grundsätzlich gehe ich davon aus, dass Rechtschreibkorrekturen in Internetbrowsers wie z. B. dem Firefox keine expliziten Regeln oder Einträge für getrennt zu schreibende Einträge haben.

Wenn ich ein Wort zusammenschreibe und die Korrektur schlägt vor, es in zwei Wörtern zu schreiben, dann heißt es doch zunächst nur, dass die zusammengeschriebene Variante nicht im Wörterbuch steht, während die einzelnen Teilwörter wohl bekannt sind. D. h., hier kann es sein, dass ein richtiges zusammengeschriebenes Wort einfach nicht im Wörterbuch steht.

Wenn eine Schreibung mit Bindestrich vorgeschlagen wird, gehe ich eigentlich davon aus, dass diese im Wörterbuch hinterlegt sein muss, also gültig sein sollte.

Generell halte ich Rechtschreibprüfprogramme bezüglich des Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibens für problematisch.

Auch ist es möglich, dass die Prüfprogramme von Textverarbeitungen qualitativ besser sind.

Comment: Das Problem ist, dass die meisten Rechtschreibprogramme einfach mit (großen) Wörterbüchern arbeiten. Es gibt anscheinend auch solche, die die Grammatik des Satzes analysieren und zusammengesetzte Substantive erkennen können, die in keinen Wörterbüchern stehen. Ohne es genau zu wissen, meine ich, dass MS Word und die Duden Korrektur das können.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Ja, die Duden-Korrektur macht das bestimmt so: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/which-spelling-is-the-right-one-deinstallieren-or-desinstallieren. Eher schlecht als recht allerdings.

Comment: @RegDwight can you vote for close like everyone else or can you only close immediately?

Comment: Wenn der Text eine Frage enthielte, hätte sie meiner Meinung nach eine gute Chance, on-topic zu sein.

Comment: Das Beispiel "Wir fingen in den Küchen Schaben." zeigt, dass richtig oder falsch zu sein keine Eigenschaft des Wortes (Eintrags) ist oder zumindest nicht immer sein kann. "Küchen-Schaben" ist m.W. in allen Sätzen falsch, außer bei Namen (Dr. Susanne Küchen-Schaben). Erst-mal wäre aber doch immer falsch, oder?